# Calculating own dft via matlab?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab

We are asked to code our own dft function from the formula :

[image: DFT Formula]

If everything is done correctly it should give the same result with matlab's own dft function, in the end I'm comparing them but they are not the same... We are not allowed to use for loops this is why Im trying to do it with matrices. Below is my code:

```
x=linspace(0,pi,10);
y=cos(x);

ones_vec = ones(10,1);
ones_vec=(ones_vec*y);

k=linspace(1,10,10);
n=linspace(0,9,10);
ones_vec_n = ones(10,1);
ones_vec_n = (ones_vec_n*n).';

ones_vec2 = ones(10,1);
ones_vec2=(ones_vec2*k*-1i*2*pi/10);
%n = n*ones_vec2.'
ones_vec2= ones_vec2 .* ones_vec_n;

dft_my = sum(ones_vec2,1)

fft_matlab = fft(y)
```

I would be glad if you can give a hand!

Comment: It'd be better not to hardcode numbers like $10$ and $9$ into your code.  There's a programming tip called "don't repeat yourself" (DRY) that would encourage you not to repeatedly type a number like $10$ ; rather just use a variable for it.

Comment: @littleO I do follow "don't repeat" usually but this code is not done yet and it is easy to follow 10 lines, when Im fully done the last version can be with variables.

Comment: As a tip: start by using loops and making the code work that way. Once you have working code, you can optimize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the following in Octave:

```
N = 128;             % FFT length
M = exp(-1i*(0:N-1)'*(0:N-1)*2*pi/N);    % DFT matrix
x = randn(128,1);    % input vector
X2 = M*x;            % DFT
X = fft(x);          % built-in FFT
error = max(abs(X-X2));    % max. magnitude of error (= 5.6474e-13)
                           % (due to numerical errors)
```

Comment: So I can put instead of `x = randn(128,1);` this `x=linspace(0,pi,128);
y=cos(x);` as well right then it should also work? I dont have matlab access now, but will try asap when I get home!Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Anarkie: Any vector of length $N$ is fine (just define $N$ as you need it).

Comment: Thank you so much for your support until now, can you please help me with my final 2 problems for this semester :( [Problem 1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833880/single-echo-fir-filter-in-matlab) and [Problem 2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/833944/multiple-echo-fir-filter-in-matlab)

Comment: @Anarkie: I'll have a look, but it might take a few day as I'm pretty busy now. Hope you can wait ...

Comment: Thanks a lot! Any result is better than no result :(

Comment: I solved Problem1 =) now only Problem2 remaining =)

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this helps:

```
dk = 0.01;
N  = 10;

[k,n] = meshgrid(0:dk:10, 0:1:N-1);

x  = cos(n);
X  = sum(x.*exp(-1i*k.*n*2*pi/N));
plot(k,abs(X));
```

I'm not very familiar with discrete Fourier's transform and I'm not sure if $X(n)$, which is a complex value, is what really should be.

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to matlab at the moment, so I can't double check this, but it's really easy to construct the DFT matrix. All you have to do is take the outer product of `0:N-1` with itself in the phase of the complex exponential:

```
N = 256;
D = exp(1j * 2*pi/N * (0:N-1)' * (0:N-1));
```

Then the DFT of a length `N` vector `x` is then just the matrix-vector product:

```
D*x
```

To check, use something like this:

```
maxerr = max(abs(fft(x) - D*x))
```